# How to call assembly functions inside Rust?

Tags: assembly, rust

I know that one way to call C functions inside Rust is to use something like this:

```
extern "C" {
    fn abs(input: i32) -> i32;
}

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        println!("abs(-3) = {}", abs(-3));
    }
}
```

But how does one call some assembly functions (located inside `.s` file in the same directory as other Rust files) inside a Rust code?

Comment: If you write your asm function to follow the C calling convention / ABI, it doesn't matter to the calling function whether you or a compiler actually wrote the asm.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Example

This is an assembly function using the C x86_64 calling convention on macOS. It doesn't segfault, so it must be right :-)

**Cargo.toml**

```
[build-dependencies]
cc = "1.0"
```

**build.rs**

```rust
fn main() {
    cc::Build::new()
        .file("add.S")
        .compile("my-asm-lib");
}
```

**add.S**

```
.text
.globl _my_adder
_my_adder:
        addq %rdi, %rsi
        movq %rsi, %rax
        ret
```

**src/main.rs**

```
extern "C" {
    fn my_adder(a: u64, b: u64) -> u64;
}

fn main() {
    let sum = unsafe { my_adder(1, 2) };
    println!("{}", sum);
}
```

## Explanation

To make use of an assembly function, there are two main pieces:

1. Compiling and linking the function
2. Calling the function

### Compiling and Linking

Rust does not inherently provide a way to compile assembly files. Instead, you have to compile them using a C compiler which already exists on the machine. The most common way of doing is is to use the [cc crate](https://crates.io/crates/cc) in a [build script](http://doc.crates.io/build-script.html).

The build script will compile your assembly files into a static library and instruct Cargo to link to the library.

You have to make sure that your assembly syntax is valid for the C compiler you are using. For example, MSVC and GCC use different assembly styles. You are likely going to need to have multiple copies of the same assembly function to handle different platforms.

### Calling

Calling the function is highly dependent on the *calling convention*. The primary calling convention is the **C calling convention**, denoted with either `extern "C"` or just plain `extern`. You may want to use the `#[link_name = "..."]` or `#[no_mangle]` attributes as well.

You can also create your own custom calling convention using a `#[naked]` function (see [RFC 1201](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1201-naked-fns.md)). You would then use assembly code on the caller side before/after the call according to its calling convention. **This is not available in stable Rust**.

There are many other calling conventions supported by Rust 1.21.1:

> cdecl, stdcall, fastcall, vectorcall, thiscall, aapcs, win64, sysv64, ptx-kernel, msp430-interrupt, x86-interrupt, Rust, C, system, rust-intrinsic, rust-call, platform-intrinsic, unadjusted

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do I somehow need to link the assembly file with Rust, so it knows from where the functions comes, or if the assembly file is in the same directory as the Rust file, Rust can figure it out?

Comment: Could you elaborate on the Rust calling convention?

Comment: @typos: I would expect you to need special commands to instruct the compiler how to link in those files in the final binary. Unfortunately, I don't know which.

Comment: @fuz: Elaborate about which aspect?

Comment: @MatthieuM. Well, what exactly is the Rust calling convention? I browsed the internet but didn't find any specification or other document laying out how Rust's calling convention works.

Comment: @fuz: It's unspecified. Rust does not commit to any specific calling convention on any target. In practice, *at the moment*, it generally happens to match the C convention; but it may change at any time in the future, for example if on a specific architecture a faster calling convention is found.

Comment: @Shepmaster: I am not suggesting anything, I am documenting what's available. I am also afraid that a number of projects may accidentally be using the Rust calling convention already today while effectively calling into C code, since it's so easy to forget the `"C"`.

Comment: Thank you @MatthieuM.  I have put the code on github and tweaked it a bit to make it compile for me: https://github.com/bitdivine/rust-call-assembler

Comment: How does this work when cross compiling for different targets? Your code example still seems to call `gcc` and not `$TARGET-gcc`. How can I change that?

Comment: @piegames: An excellent question to which I have no answer, unfortunately. If you could not find the answer on Stack Overflow, I invite you to make a stand-alone question out of it and I hope someone more knowledgeable will be able to chime in.

Answer (score 3):

Completing [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47455865/8825700) :

If you use nightly rust, you can avoid using a custom build script by using the [global_asm! macro](https://doc.rust-lang.org/unstable-book/library-features/global-asm.html).

> A simple usage looks like this:
>
> ```rust
> #[feature(global_asm)]
>
> ...
>
> global_asm!(include_str!("something_neato.s"));
> ```