# Is there any way to use inline assembly or any other way to use assembly on unsupported architecture in Rust language?

Tags: assembly, rust, llvm

The title is probably too long...

I'm new to embed Rust. And I'm writing a program involves the usage of assembly in Rust.

I saw [Rust by Example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/rust-by-example/unsafe/asm.html), which says:

```
Inline assembly is currently supported on the following architectures:

x86 and x86-64
ARM
AArch64
RISC-V
```

So what if I want to use assembly on other architectures (eg powerpc, sparc)? Should I write independent assembly file and (in some way) stick the rust code and assembly together? Or there are some hacky ways to achieve this in Rustc or LLVM?

Comment: You can use [non-inline assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47455163/555045) (example is x64 but should be generalizable)

Comment: *Or there are some hacky ways to achieve this in Rustc or LLVM?* - Like adding support for more ISAs to Rustc, with constraints and so on and whatever other internals are needed for register allocation?  I'd expect patches are welcome, although it's probably a lot of work, and if there are people already working on any more ISAs, you'd want to coordinate with their design discussions and maybe use their code as a starting point.  Or do you mean actually hacky like `naked` functions that are basically equivalent to putting an asm function in a separate `.S` file.